# ASP to PHP translate - string concatenation

Tags: php, asp-classic

I am having trouble translating string concatenation from ASP to PHP. I am using automatic translators and probably the error happens because \ is an escape quote in PHP.

For example,

```
caminhoMP3 = Application("Root")&"_content\img\musica\musica_"&MusicaIDAux&"\"&ArquivoMP3Aux
```

is translated

```
$caminhoMP3 = Application("Root")."_content\img\musica\musica_".$MusicaIDAux."\".$ArquivoMP3Aux;
```

or

```
$caminhoMP3=."_content\img\musica\musica_".$MusicaIDAux."\".$ArquivoMP3Aux;
```

Comment: That's an issue. Just add an extra slash `"\\"` or use single quotes around the string with the slash `'\'`. Also `=.` isn't valid as concatenation, but `.=` is.

Answer (score 3):

Your right, the backslash would essentially escape the quote ". So you need to escape your slash too (by adding an additional one).

```
$caminhoMP3 = Application("Root")."content\img\musica\musica".$MusicaIDAux."\\".$ArquivoMP3Aux;
```